# Running Hive through Oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sqoop, oozie

I'm facing some issues while running hive through oozie. In the oozie console, I'm getting the following error:

```
2013-05-03 04:48:24,248  WARN HiveActionExecutor:542 - USER[ambari_qa] GROUP[-] TOKEN[]  APP[hive-wf] JOB[0000013-130502155316029-oozie-oozi-W] 
ACTION[0000013-130502155316029-  oozie-oozi-W@hive-node] Launcher exception:    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    
org.apache.hcatalog.security.HdfsAuthorizationProvider
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hcatalog.security.HdfsAuthorizationProvider
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:293)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.runHive(HiveMain.java:303)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.run(HiveMain.java:280)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.main(HiveMain.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:467)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1178)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hcatalog.security.HdfsAuthorizationProvider
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:287)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hcatalog.security.HdfsAuthorizationProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthorizeProviderManager(HiveUtils.java:335)
... 20 more
```

I have mentioned the system classpath in my job.properties file. Here is my job properties file:

```
nameNode=hdfs://ip-10-0-0-92:8020
jobTracker=ip-10-0-0-93:50300
queueName=default
wfeRoot=wfe

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib/hive

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${wfeRoot}/hive-oozie
```

And here is my workflow.xml file:

```
<action name="hive-node">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
     <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
     <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${wfeRoot}/output-data/hive"/>
            <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${wfeRoot}/output-data"/>
        </prepare>
     <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
      <property>
                <name>oozie.log.hive.level</name>
                <value>DEBUG</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                <value>hive-default.xml</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>script.q</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

I have copied hive-site.xml & hive-default.xml files into hdfs.

Any idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error when I did not have the jars for HCatalog in my Oozie ShareLib folder. This line in your error output is what gives it away.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hcatalog.security.HdfsAuthorizationProvider
```

To verfiy, run

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/oozie/share/lib/hive | grep hcatalog
```

You should expect to see both hcatalog-core-0.5.0 and hcatalog-server-extensions-0.5.0 (the version might be different depending on how your distribution packages it).

The solution is to run the following. You will need to run it as `hdfs` (or whichever user is your cluster's root user) by running `sudo su hdfs` if `dfs.permissions = true` on your cluster.

```
cd /usr/lib/hcatalog/share/hcatalog
ls
hadoop fs -put hcatalog-core-0.5.0.jar /user/oozie/share/lib/hive
hadoop fs -put hcatalog-server-extensions-0.5.0.jar /user/oozie/share/lib/hive
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/oozie/share/lib/hive/hcatalog-core-0.5.0.jar
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/oozie/share/lib/hive/hcatalog-server-extensions-0.5.0.jar
```

Again, the exact file names and file paths will vary by Hadoop distribution. I'm suggesting 777 permissions (read, write, and execute for all owner, group, and all other users) because it is the most permissive and will guarantee to get you through this bug. If you have security concerns, different permissions might be required. You can look at the other files in the folder to get a reasonable default.

This problem can occur when setting up or upgrading a new Hadoop cluster if your distributions upgrade tools/documentation miss this step.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks a lot, that was the issue and it's now fixed. Though I'm not seeing any such error on my oozie console but my job is still failing. What other places I should look to find some relevant logs?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could save someone else the time I spend figuring that one out. To check out logs I go to the Oozie Web Console, select the job that failed, select the action that failed, the go to the Console URL for that action. It will report as successful because the Oozie job didn't crash even though the action failed. Click on the successful Map task, then the task id, and then "All" in the task logs (I've yet to hit an Oozie task log where "All" was big enough to crash my browser). Hopefully that helps you out. If not go ahead and post a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot again @Daniel, I was able to find the root cause from that log location. Log from that location was really helpful. I forgot to give read permission to those jar files while copying them to hdfs. After giving 'write' permission job execution was successful. Thanks again.

Comment: @Daniel - thanks for a good answer, but you really need to add the extra chmod steps, otherwise your answer is not complete. Like tanzir, I found that you have to do `hadoop fs -chmod 777` on those two jars.  You should also say that you have to su to the hdfs user to do those actions. Thanks again.

Comment: @tanzir and midpeter444 Thanks for the suggestion, I have incorporated the permission changes in my answer.